# setting cookies directly in Rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-2

**Motivation:** I'm solving problems that are caused by strange/mutated/odd/perverse cookies in ruby-on-rails. I have captured some of these evil cookies and I can use cookie manager on firefox to recreate the cookie state to replicate the problems. I want to write a rails page that will automate the task of setting these cookies.

**Problem:** If I change or delete the _myapp_session cookie in a rails controller, it issues me a new one. For example the following change to _myapp_session will never be seen by the user.

```
cookies[:_myapp_session] = 'abcedf'
```

I want to recreate the exact cookies for my domain that a user has including invalid or corrupted cookies. How can I get this low level with rails2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't create a new one. Are the cookies of a different domain than the source domain of the page? If so, you can set the domain on the cookies by passing a block to the cookie -setter method.

```
cookies[cookie_name] = {
    :value => 'your value',
    :expires => 1.week.from_now,
    :domain => 'sub.yourdomain.com'
}
```

Comment: Not of a different domain, rails just has it's hand in the cookie jar and overwrites whatever you put in _myapp_session.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. All the variables in your session can be accessed via session[:var]. If you're using the cookie store for your session object, then you shouldn't ever modify the session cookie directly. What evidence do you have to support the perverse cookies, if you don't mind me asking? Maybe add that to your post?

Comment: The issues of corrupted cookies are a different, diverse and continuing issue that goes beyond a simple SO question. I don't want to "support" perverse cookies, but rather induce them for debugging purposes. Yes I could copy the session variables for good session cookies, but what about a session cookie that has been corrupted on a byte level? I want the bit for bit cookie replication that I can get using a firefox plugin.